# testing some asynchronous code by polling a probe?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, message, polling

I'm trying to test something that could be considered a messaging server. To make the story short and simple, let say that i have a client that send a message to a server. I want to test the message that is received by the server.

My server is launched as such:

```
Thread(ois).start();
```

ois is indeed a runnable.

For simplicity reason every time my server receives a message from its incoming network interface, through a blocking queue, it store that message in a variable, and then go on to do some treatment on it (after what it put back the variable to null/None) and then goes back to pick a new message from the queue that it store on the same variable. The content of that variable is accessible from the outside by calling a getter method that is synchronized (I think about doing a defensive copy here).

What i would like to do is to use a technique that is called, polling and probing.  From within my test I'd like to check that my server indeed received a message, and that this message is conform to some spec.

I red something about the concept of polling a probe from "growing object-oriented software with Test". After re-reading few times the chapter on that technique i still can't figure out how exactly that shall works. Basically, in that chapter the author explain that when it comes to testing asynchronous code in end-to-end, one approach is listening, but require event coming back from the asynchronous code, and the other is sampling which is about polling a probe.

I was wondering if someone understand that concept well, and could tell me how i could move forward on that with my current system.

From my test, shall i just use something like awaitility, and check that my variable is not null and then copy it to test its content? Will i not run on thread issue, or synchronization issue? Is it the right approach?

Many thanks.

PS:

It is a background thread in a GUI application. I have stubbed out the GUI part for the matter.

Comment: You seem to mix a real existing implementation with some very theoretical wording stuff. Can you explain why you think that what you are doing now (getting the contents of a variable via a method at a some point of time) is *not* “polling a probe”? Or, asked the other way: if you don’t understand what kind of concept the book is explaining, why do you think that you need or want it?

Comment: the problem is in the design of my code. that variable should not be visible anyhow. It is an implementation detail. I must hide that

Comment: I think i found some good solution in: is this the way to go as of now, or is there anything newer more handy :
http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.AsyncAssertions

Comment: which is inspired from the java work 
https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit

Comment: If i understand well this approach. The idea would be to have a "message handler" that one inject in his messaging infrastructure to treat message once received. Therefore, for testing purpose, one could inject a mock that does some asynchronous assertions. Although i would prefer to do the assertion within the main thread. I don't know if the usage of Scala future might help here. Not yet fully familiar with it but i need to dig in it. Do you have any knowledge of it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this concept, but here is a small trick which could be useful for any multithreaded test (originally it won't fail without ErrorCollector because exceptions in a separate thread are not visible by JUnit runner ):

```
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                collector.addError(e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fail();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
```